# Java multithreading - initialize array and sum

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I have a problem that I'm working on where I need to:

- Initialize an array of any given size, where each value of the array will be assigned by 1 thread. So there are as many threads as the length of the array. This has to be done using a static field and cannot be done through a thread constructor
- Sequentially sum the array (from 0 to n) using each each thread, cannot make thread wait if it isn't the next thread to sum, must use a wait/notify.

Could anyone provide some general direction how I could accomplish this? Right now there are problems with synchronization and I'm not sure how to solve them, sometimes values in the array are input as 0 or the summing isn't correct.

```
public class Processor {

    static volatile int numberOfValues = 17;
    static double processedArray[];
    static Thread threadsArray[];
    static volatile int sum;
    static Object lock1 = new Object();
    static Object lock2 = new Object();
```

Adding values to the array. Sometimes zeroes are added instead of the next number from numberOfValues

```
    private static void initializeArray() {
        threadsArray = new Thread[numberOfValues];
        processedArray = new double[numberOfValues];

        for (int i = 0; i < threadsArray.length; i++) {
            threadsArray[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    synchronize(lock1) {
                        processedArray[numberOfValues - 1] = numberOfValues;
                        numberOfValues--;
                    }

                }   
            });
            threadsArray[i].start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < threadsArray.length; i++) {
            try {
                threadsArray[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Summing the values in the array, doesn't always sum to be correct (in this case where the sum is all numbers from 1-17)

```
        for (int i = 0; i < threadsArray.length; i++) {
            threadsArray[i] = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    synchronize(lock2) {
                        sum += processedArray[numberOfValues];
                        numberOfValues++;
                    }       

                }   
            });
            threadsArray[i].start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < threadsArray.length; i++) {
            try {
                threadsArray[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Main

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        initializeArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < threadsArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(processedArray[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've posted a lot of code. What is the problem with it exactly? What did you expect to happen (and where in the code) and what is actually happening instead? Please be specific, that will make your question more answerable.

Comment: I suggest you use IntStream and parallelStream.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I added some changes, thank you for the advice.

Comment: You've got multiple threads reading and writing the value of `numberOfValues`.  Those 2 lines of code in the run() method need to be atomic, e.g. wrapped in a `synchronized` block.

Comment: And same for `sum`: it' is shared state modified from concurrent threads. It must be synchronized

Comment: I'm pretty unclear on your second bullet point.  "Sequentially sum the array (from 0 to n) using **each each** thread",  Sequentially confuses me.  Using multiple threads usually implies asynchronous execution, and if you mean an arithmetic sequence, it doesn't matter what order you sum integers.  I think "threads" has made you tie yourself into a knot, and you need to think about the actual problem statement a bit more.

Comment: Thank you. I've made changes above the code blocks within run() to be synchronized and made sum volatile. It seems to be working now.

Comment: @markspace apologies if it is confusing, I'm under the assumption that the idea is to practice with threads and to try to make them run sequentially, i.e. each one has an index value and making them sum from 0 to n rather than asynchronously. I agree it doesn't matter in any case